# Show the continuity of a function between vector space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, continuity, normed-spaces

I consider the function defined by $\phi(f)$ which associates to each function $f$ from $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ the function $\phi(f)(x) = \int_{0}^{x} tf(t)dt$ from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

My idea is first to show that for all $f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, $\phi(f)(x)$ is a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ :

Let us take $x_1,x_2$ in $[0,1]$. We have :

$$ 
\lvert \phi(f)(x_1) - \phi(f)(x_2)\rvert = \left\lvert\int_{0}^{x_1} tf(t)dt - \int_{0}^{x_2} tf(t)dt\right\rvert = \left\lvert \int_{x_1}^{x_2} tf(t)dt\right\rvert\leq\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \lvert t\rvert dt C 
$$

Where $C = \sup\{\lvert f(t)\rvert\}$

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Now by continuity of $\lvert t\rvert$ in $0$, let $\varepsilon_1> 0$. We have
$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \lvert t\rvert dt\leq \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\varepsilon_1 dt$.

Take $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{C\varepsilon_1}$. We get

$$ 
\lvert \phi(f)(x_1) - \phi(f)(x_2)\rvert \leq \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\varepsilon_1 dtC =(x_2-x_1)\varepsilon_1C\leq \varepsilon_1\delta =\varepsilon
$$

Thus $\phi$ is a mapping from $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ to $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. It can be shown that it is a linear mapping using the linearity of the integral. Thus to look for its continuity it suffices to look at the continuity at $0$ the null mapping from $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ to $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

For all $x\in [0,1]$ we have :

$$ 
\left\lvert\int_{0}^{x}tf(t)dt\right\rvert\leq\int_{0}^{x}\lvert t\rvert dt\lVert f\rVert_{\infty} = \frac{x^2}{2}\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}\leq\frac{1}{2}\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}
$$

Which shows that $\lVert\phi(f)\rVert_{\infty}\leq\frac{1}{2}\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}$

Which prove the continuity of $\phi$.

I would like to know if it is correct and also if you are aware on a more efficient way to prove this ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Yes this is correct, however for the first part, you could have just said that the primitive of a continuous function is continuous

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace  You are totally right yes. Thank you !

Comment: In your final inequality you should write $\|\phi(f)\|_\infty$ instead of $\|\phi(f)(x)\|_\infty$, since the norm is applied to functions.

Comment: @Gerd Yes it was not correct, thank you !